# SQL query syntax error using INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access

So, I know my code for the database connection and reader is functional, because it has worked for me many times before, however, something about this SQL query:
[image]
gives this error message:
[image]

when this data is inputted:
[image]
This is the database table that I am trying to add the data to:
[image]

Comment: The sql of the statement would have been useful...

Comment: It is in the pictures and seems to be correct.

Comment: Please copy the sql in your question even if it is in the pictures. In the picture we or you could oversee some charactars or whitespaces.

Comment: Not something daft like password is reserved word is it?

Comment: Try removing the line feed you add to the query.

Comment: Is according to this. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: You're right. I looked up an old list where password was not included.

Comment: Is Jet in your connection string, if so [password] is worth a try

Comment: @juergend. Yeah I looked it up in access first, is in Jet 4.0 though. If it isn't that, I'm clueless as to what could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using "password" as a column name and that's a reserved word in Jet SQL.  Either change the name or escape it in SQL code.  You do the latter by wrapping it in square brackets `[]`.

Comment: According to this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738 this answer is correct, did you try it?

Comment: @juergend, you should probably learn something before you speak. An MDB file is a Jet database, plain and simple.  Access is an application that was created to provide easy access to Jet databases.  More recently, i.e. with Office 2007, the ACCDB file format was created and an ACCDB file can genuinely be called an Access database but, even then, it still supports the same SQL syntax as Jet, although presumably with some additions.  If the OP is using an MDB file then they are using a Jet database and therefore Jet SQL.  If they're using an ACCDB file then they're still basically using Jet SQL.